# How do I use the awk command in Bash to pull a result from the 2nd column with the number 5 in the same row while also ignoring other rows?

Tags: awk

To clarify

Here is an example document

```
5,cat 
55,dog
555,mouse
5555,crow
```

How would I use awk to get just cat as a result?

I tried:

```
$ awk -F ',' '/5/ {print $2}' filename
```

which pulled up every animal.

Answer (score 2):

Like this, without regex but string comparison:

```
$ awk -F ',' '$1==5 {print $2}' filename
```

or with a regex:

```
$ awk -F ',' '$1 ~ /^5$/ {print $2}' filename
```